# Lazy Loading of property in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

Is the latest entity framework finally able to lazy load properties (e.g. byte[] ) without doing that table splitting hack?

Comment: By "latest", do you mean the latest release, the latest prerelease, or the recently open sourced to-be-EF6 codebase? As far as I know, it doesn't change the answer, but it changes the certainty with which I would say "I don't think so".

Comment: the latest publically available version :)

Comment: All of those are publicly available, so that would be the EF6 codebase then. In that case, I don't think so, but I'm not sure enough to answer :)

Comment: ok then lets wait for someone posting a link here about that feature.

Comment: One work-around to "the table splitting hack" is to create a view of the table that doesn't have the large field, and then create an EF object that references the view - works quite well. Yes, you have two entities in EF, but the storage is automatically consistent between the two, and it keeps the DB side simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is [not able to lazy load columns](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1051513-lazy-loading-at-property-column-level) without table splitting. As you can see the suggestion is even not yet switched to planned or under review state. Table splitting workaround solves this problem.

[EF is now open source](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/) so you can add that feature yourselves.

Comment: "so you can add that feature yourselves" and get busy till end of this year :P